# JQUERY click event not children

Tags: jquery, click

I have a click event in .content, but i wouldn't the event with children.. .not() selector doesn't works..

```
<ul class="content">
    <li><a href="#" class="object">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="object">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="object">...</a></li>
</ul>

$(".content").click(function() {
  $( ".object", this ).slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: not getting actually what you want? can you please describe in detail?

Comment: are you trying to slide toggle the contents (list items) of div.content? if yes try $(".content").click(function() {
  $( "li").slideToggle();
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
$(".content").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target == this) //Making sure you're on the parent, no children
        $( ".object", this ).slideToggle();
});
```